# SQLite android ALTER COLUMN help

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I know that i need to implement `ALTER COLUMN`.

But I have no idea where I need to implement this at in my SQL Database.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you need to do exactly we'd be able to help more...

Answer (score 1):

ALTER COLUMN doesnt exist in SQLite. If you are trying to ALTER TABLE you can do that but support is limited. Read more here [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)